# Visual Basic Editor in 2013

Tags: excel-2013

I have opened the developer tab in excel 2013. However, I cannot open the Visual Basic Editor, in which I can open in excel 2007/2010 in a blank form?

Is there any settings I have to make, can anyone help figure it out?

Comment: Is the VBA editor installed? Isn't it an optional component?

Answer (score 0):

Just press Alt + F11. That will open the VBE in any Excel version.

Also, I see no reason that it should not open. I tried it just now on my computer and it works fine (using the developer tab). Most probably you have a problem of some sorts with your "installation" of Office 2013.

Comment: The quotes around the word installation in your answer sound like you're questioning the validity of his installation, perhaps even the license. You have absolutely no reason for that.

Comment: I am not. English is my second language and I wasn't sure this was the correct word to use here.